# VF Performance Issue

Tags: soql, performance

Salesforce recently notified us that "a VF is consuming high levels of DB resources due to inefficient SOQL in your VF controller."

I believe I have identified the issue down to this query:

```
sPreviewQuery += ' AND ID NOT IN(SELECT i361__Marketing_Task__c FROM i361__Campaign_Member__c Where i361__Completed_On__c =null AND i361__Campaign__c != '+ sCurrentID +')';
```

Essentially we want that query to return all tasks that haven't been completed and are in a different campaign than the current. The problem is there are a large amount of marketing tasks and a large amount of campaign members.

I am stuck on how to optimize this query to increase performance. And idea I've had is to create a set of campaign members to use instead of querying directly.

Comment: How many tasks are being returned and how are you displaying them? You could chunk the query using an offset and only display a subset of incomplete tasks

Comment: @greenstork I am in the process of figuring that out. Simple system.debug() statements would work for that purpose, correct?

Comment: By the way, NOT IN (and !=) can't leverage the index, as opposed to LIKE '...%' (trailing wildcard), IN, and =. That's what they're talking about consuming large amounts of resources. Can you figure out a way use positive criteria instead of negative criteria?

Comment: You might want to watch this video on performance tuning from DF13: http://youtu.be/aYMY2VES2bY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We neither see all of your relevant code to figure your custom data model nor the entire query.

So assuming that your main query also selects from  i361__Marketing_Task__c you should try to get rid of the subselect. Hot to do it precisely depends on your data model.

Better utilization of the index as @sfdcfox mentioned or cached fields directly on i361__Marketing_Task__c (maintained by a trigger) could improve your performance.